# Find distribution of consecutive zeros

Tags: r

I have a vector, say `x` which contains only the integer numbers `0`,`1` and `2`. For example;

```
x <- c(0,1,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0)
```

From this I would like to extract how many times zero occurs in each "pattern". In this simple example it occurs three times on it own, twice as `00` and exactly once as `000`, so I would like to output something like:

```
0      3
00     2
000    1
```

My actual dataset is quite large (1000-2000 elements in the vector) and at least in theory the maximum number of consecutive zeros is `length(x)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight This question was answered, and marked as answered quite a while ago, so I don't quite see the point of this comment ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1)** We can use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
data.table(x)[, strrep(0, sum(x==0)) ,rleid(x == 0)][V1 != "",.N , V1]
#    V1 N
#1:   0 3
#2:  00 2
#3: 000 1
```

---

**2)** or we can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x) %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(x != 0)) %>% 
    filter(x == 0)  %>% 
    count(grp) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    count(n)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     n    nn
#   <int> <int>
#1     1     3
#2     2     2
#3     3     1
```

---

**3)**  Or we can use `tabulate` with `rleid`

```
tabulate(tabulate(rleid(x)[x==0]))
#[1] 3 2 1
```

#### Benchmarks

By checking with `system.time` on @SymbolixAU's dataset

```
system.time({
  tabulate(tabulate(rleid(x2)[x2==0]))
 })
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.03    0.00    0.03
```

Comparing with the `Rcpp` function, the above is not that bad

```
 system.time({
  m <- zeroPattern(x2)
  m[m[,2] > 0, ]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.01    0.01    0.03
```

With `microbenchmark`, removed the methods that are consuming more time (based on @SymbolixAU's comparisons) and initiated a new comparison.  Note that here also, it is not exactly apples to apples but it is still a lot more similar as in the previous comparison there is an overhead of `data.table` along with some formatting to replicate the OP's expected output

```
microbenchmark(
    akrun = {
        tabulate(tabulate(rleid(x2)[x2==0]))
    },
    G = {
        with(rle(x2), table(lengths[values == 0]))
    },
    sym = {
        m <- zeroPattern(x2)
        m[m[,2] > 0, ]
    },
    times = 5, unit = "relative"
)
#Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# akrun 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000     5  a 
#     G 6.049181 8.272782 5.353175 8.106543 7.527412 2.905924     5   b
#   sym 1.385976 1.338845 1.661294 1.399635 3.845435 1.211131     5  a
```

Comment: The double `tabulate` method is surprising/impressive.

Answer (score 21):

**1) rle** Use `rle` and `table` like this.  No packages are needed.

```
tab <- with(rle(x), table(lengths[values == 0]))
```

giving:

```
> tab
1 2 3 
3 2 1
```

or

```
> as.data.frame(tab)
  Var1 Freq
1    1    3
2    2    2
3    3    1
```

That is, there are 3 runs of one zero, 2 runs of two zeros and 1 run of three zeros.

The output format in the question is not really feasible if there are very long runs but just for fun here it is:

```
data.frame(Sequence = strrep(0, names(tab)), Freq = as.numeric(tab))
```

giving:

```
  Sequence Freq
1        0    3
2       00    2
3      000    1
```

**2) gregexpr** Another possibility is to use a regular expression:

```
tab2 <- table(attr(gregexpr("0+", paste(x, collapse = ""))[[1]], "match.length"))
```

giving:

```
> tab2
1 2 3 
3 2 1
```

Other output formats could be derived as in (1).

### Note

I checked the speed with a `length(x)` of 2000 and (1) took about 1.6 ms on my laptop and (2) took about 9 ms.

Comment: Have added a new section (2) with a different approach.

Answer (score 7):

You mention a 'quite large' data set, so you can make use of C++ through `Rcpp` to speed this up (however, the benchmarking shows base `rle` solution is fairly quick anyway)

A function could be

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('Rcpp::NumericMatrix zeroPattern(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
  int consecutive_counter = 0;
  Rcpp::IntegerVector iv = seq(1, x.length());

  Rcpp::NumericMatrix m(x.length(), 2);  
  m(_, 0) = iv;

  for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    if (x[i] == 0) {
      consecutive_counter++;
    } else if (consecutive_counter > 0) {
      m(consecutive_counter-1, 1)++;
      consecutive_counter = 0;
    }
  }
  if (consecutive_counter > 0) {
    m(consecutive_counter-1, 1)++;
  }

  return m;
}')
```

Which gives you a matrix of the counts of consecutive zeros

```
x <- c(0,1,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0)

zeroPattern(x)
m <- zeroPattern(x)
m[m[,2] > 0, ]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    2
# [3,]    3    1
```

On a larger data set we notice the speed improvements

```
set.seed(20180411)
x2 <- sample(x, 1e6, replace = T)

m <- zeroPattern(x2)
m[m[,2] > 0, ]

library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
microbenchmark(
    akrun = {
        data.table(x2)[, strrep(0, sum(x2==0)) ,rleid(x2 == 0)][V1 != "",.N , V1]
    },
    G = {
        with(rle(x2), table(lengths[values == 0]))
    },
    sym = {
        m <- zeroPattern(x2)
        m[m[,2] > 0, ]
    },
    times = 5
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr        min         lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
# akrun 3727.66899 3782.19933 3920.9151 3887.6663 4048.2275 4158.8132     5
#     G  236.69043  237.32251  258.4320  246.1470  252.1043  319.8956     5
#   sym   97.54988   98.76986  190.3309  225.2611  237.5781  292.4955     5
```

---

Note:

Mine and G's functions are returning a 'table'-style answer. Akrun has formatted his to include padded zeros, so will incur a slight cost.